# Paraview with polydata

Tags: polygon, paraview

Trying to plot a "cylinder" (modification of the paraview->source->alphabetical->cylinder)
but can not figure out why is not the last polygon (end cap) plotted.
[image]
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 16 float
0.5         0.5     0
0.353553    0.5     -0.353553
0.          0.5     -0.5
-0.353553   0.5     -0.353553
-0.5        0.5     0.
-0.353553   0.5     0.353553
0.          0.5     0.5
0.353553    0.5     0.353553
0.353553    -0.5    0.353553
0.          -0.5    0.5
-0.353553   -0.5    0.353553
-0.5        -0.5    0.
-0.353553   -0.5    -0.353553
0.          -0.5    -0.5
0.353553    -0.5    -0.353553
0.5         -0.5    0
POLYGONS 10 48
OFFSETS vtktypeint64
0 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
CONNECTIVITY vtktypeint64
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   15  14  1
1   14  13  2
2   13  12  3
3   12  11  4
4   11  10  5
5   10  9   6
6   9   8   7
7   8   15  0
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not correctly formatted to define the last polygonal face.

You should add the last point index in the `OFFSETS` list and thus increment the number of indices declared in `POLYGONS`. See here:

```
POLYGONS 11 48
OFFSETS vtktypeint64
0 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 48
```

The full correct file:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
vtk output 
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 16 float
0.5 0.5 0
0.353553 0.5 -0.353553
0. 0.5 -0.5
-0.353553 0.5 -0.353553
-0.5 0.5 0.
-0.353553 0.5 0.353553
0. 0.5 0.5
0.353553 0.5 0.353553
0.353553 -0.5 0.353553
0. -0.5 0.5
-0.353553 -0.5 0.353553
-0.5 -0.5 0.
-0.353553 -0.5 -0.353553
0. -0.5 -0.5
0.353553 -0.5 -0.353553
0.5 -0.5 0

POLYGONS 11 48
OFFSETS vtktypeint64
0 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 48
CONNECTIVITY vtktypeint64
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 15 14 1
1 14 13 2
2 13 12 3
3 12 11 4
4 11 10 5
5 10 9 6
6 9 8 7
7 8 15 0
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Hum, yes it works, but if I have only 10 polygons, why do we have to specify 11?

Comment: Would there be a way to specify the color of the generated cylinder?

Comment: 11 is the size of the OFFSETS array, that includes starting offset for each poly but also the ending offset of the last poly.